# Where to find most of datasheets?

Tags: microcontroller, arm, datasheet, documentation

I am trying to find a datasheet for one of the following cores: BCM11311 or bcm21654.
Which have an ARMv7-A architecture and ARM cortex 9 processor.
However I am completely unable to find any usefull datasheet of the BCM11311 or bcm21654 on the internet. I have seen there is code available to port freertos to a cortex A9 processor, so I am looking for any chip which has this architecture. So I can lookup all the register addresses and analyze all the code.

Why can't I find a datasheet of any of these?

Comment: Those are Broadcom parts.  It looks like they don't have the datasheet publicly available for download, but you should be able to request it.  Try to sign up for an account on their website or e-mail them.

Comment: You may also have trouble actually getting hold of the parts..

Comment: There are manufacturers who just ignore you if you don't come to them with 6-digit sales volume figures. Broadcom is known to be one of them. If you had to ask this question here, I'm afraid it means Broadcom won't be interested in your project, whatever it is...